# Apache virtualhost error missing dependencies

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am trying to simply set up a virtual host which ive done a million times. however right now im getting the following error:

```
10:01:11  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:01:11  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:01:11  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:01:11  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:01:11  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:01:11  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:01:11  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

my hosts file looks like this:

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       system.local
```

And my httpd-vhosts file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost system.local>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\system"
    ServerName system.local
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\system">
        Order allow, deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone tell me why im getting this error?

Error log:

```
    [Wed Sep 03 09:39:22.802060 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3992:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:23.145261 2014] [core:warn] [pid 3992:tid 268] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:23.332461 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3992:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:25.126464 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3992:tid 268] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:25.126464 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3992:tid 268] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:25.126464 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3992:tid 268] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:25.142064 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3992:tid 268] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4896
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:25.968866 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4896:tid 280] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:26.218466 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4896:tid 280] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:39:26.343266 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4896:tid 280] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:20.207001 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6980:tid 264] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:20.268004 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6980:tid 264] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:20.430013 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6980:tid 264] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:20.613024 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6980:tid 264] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:20.613024 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6980:tid 264] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:20.613024 2014] [core:notice] [pid 6980:tid 264] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:20.633025 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6980:tid 264] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6784
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:21.453072 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6784:tid 280] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:21.666084 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6784:tid 280] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 03 09:59:21.703086 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6784:tid 280] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: The error message tells you what you should do to find more information about the error … so what was the result of you doing that?

Comment: @CBroe ive posted my error log

Comment: Those are only warnings/notices, none of that is an actual error that would cause Apache to shut down. Can you check Windows Event Viewer as well?

Comment: Try to replace `<VirtualHost learningbank.local>` by `<VirtualHost *>`. using a name there is not recommended (from the documentation). Not sure it would solve the problem.

Comment: Tried but with no effect